# Using FastAPI to get list of containers present on my local, not working

Tags: python, linux, docker, fastapi

So basically I have a FastAPI that should return list of containers on my local I am trying to access the unix socket it works on my command line and shows the containers if I curl it on the command line but when coding it, it shows issues. I have attached the FastAPI and the linux command should someone show me the right way to go for it.

I tried doing it through local first but turns out I should have gone through linux socket. If anyone has an idea, how to fix it let me know what im doing wrong

below is my main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from httpx import ConnectError
import httpx
import logging

app = FastAPI()

DOCKER_API_UNIX_SOCKET = "http+unix://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock"

async def get_containers():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(f"{DOCKER_API_UNIX_SOCKET}/v1.41/containers/json")
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()

@app.get("/containers")
async def list_containers():
    try:
        containers = await get_containers()
        return containers
    except ConnectError as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to connect to Docker API: {str(e)}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal Server Error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

this is my docker file

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 8000 and 2375 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 2375

# Define environment variable
ENV DOCKER_API_URL http://host.docker.internal:2375  # Update if needed

# Run main.py when the container launches
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload"]
```

Here is the linux command that shows me the containers

```
curl --silent --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock  http://v1.41/containers/json
```

This is the error msg

```
    INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [8]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     172.17.0.1:53652 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     172.17.0.1:53656 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     172.17.0.1:53656 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     172.17.0.1:53656 - "GET /containers HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 373, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 219, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 152, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/app/./main.py", line 19, in list_containers
    containers = await get_containers()
  File "/app/./main.py", line 12, in get_containers
    response = await client.get(f"{DOCKER_API_UNIX_SOCKET}/v1.41/containers/json")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1786, in get
    return await self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1559, in request
    return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1646, in send
    response = await self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1674, in _send_handling_auth
    response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1711, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = await self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1748, in _send_single_request
    response = await transport.handle_async_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 371, in handle_async_request
    resp = await self._pool.handle_async_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 84, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.UnsupportedProtocol: Request URL has an unsupported protocol 'http+unix://'.
```

Comment: *" it shows issues"* It is expected that you present the issues in the question and in details.

Comment: Checkout how to use httpx with UNIX sockets: https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#custom-transports